# How can I paginate two Eloquent collections on a single page with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two collections on a single page which should be both paginated. But pagination generates the same Parameter for both (?page=X).

How can I solve that kind of an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the param of either pagination by

`Paginator::setPageName('someparam');`

Read more about Pagination [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination) In the section `Customizing The Paginator URI`

**Note :** You should do this before paginator is done i.e.,

`$yourCollection = Model::paginate(10);`

**Example :**

I assume you have two pagination like this

```
Paginator::setPageName('yourFirstParam');
$firstCollection = FirstModel::paginate(10);

Paginator::setPageName('yourSecondParam');
$secondCollection = SecondModel::paginate(10);
```

Where you use this to get in your view

```
Paginator::setPageName('yourFirstParam');
$firstCollection->links();
Paginator::setPageName('yourSecondParam');
$secondCollection->links();
```

Comment: Work great, but the problem now is that somehow Laravel always returns the First Page results :( I have done a quick search and a lot of other devs have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. I can find something While i dig into `Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php`. Can you look into it ?

Comment: I have checked there, and also abstract paginator, but could not find anything related to the problem. Also in your comment, that I should run setPageName before the pagination - how can I do this? If i don't run the paginate method, I can't get a Paginator instance and thus, can't run setPageName before it :(

Comment: You are totally right concerning setPageName, because when I remove it the pagination works correctly. Now I just can't move it because I don't have a paginator instance :(

Comment: You mean, you can't see the target file ?

Comment: No no, I have already found the solution. The paginate() method allows to set the page name as a third parameter. I did that and it worked. And if I use ->setPageName() explicitly, it does not work, because It changes the page name, but resets the ->pagination() method so the results and pagination are like I am at the first page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to "automatically" set the page name (in a sense), which I'll get to in a bit.

First, if we go over the [`paginate` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L271), you'll see that it accepts a `pageName` argument as its 3rd parameter:

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
```

Lets say you have a `User` and `Post` model. You can then do something like this in your controller:

```
$users = User::paginate(10, ['*'], 'users');
$posts = Post::paginate(10, ['*'], 'posts');
return view('example', compact('users', 'posts'));
```

It works like your normal pagination except the second argument specifies the columns you want to select and the third argument specifies the page name.

In your view, when you render your pagination links, you might run into a problem when you do this:

```
{!! $users->render() !!}
{!! $posts->render() !!}
```

While the pagination links will be rendered, when you click on a link to a posts page, the users query string parameter is gone. Therefore, the users are back to page one and vice versa.

To fix this, you can use the [`appends` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L171) to keep the query parameters for both models:

```
{!! $users->appends(['posts' => Request::query('posts')])->render() !!}
{!! $posts->appends(['users' => Request::query('users')])->render() !!}
```

All this works, but it's a bit ugly so how can we clean this up? You can create your own method to "automate" this process. In your model, you can add your own paginate method:

```
// Name it whatever you want, but I called it superPaginate lol
protected function superPaginate($perPage)
{
    return $this->newQuery()->paginate(10, ['*'], $this->getTable());
}
```

This will automatically set the pagination name to the model's table name. So for the `User` model, the page name will be "users". For the `Post` model, the page name will be "posts".

There's still the problem with rendering links. You don't want to call `appends` all the time and specify the query parameters. To fix that, we can improve the `superPaginate` method into this:

```
protected function superPaginate($perPage, $columns = ['*'], $page = null)
{
    $params = \Request::query();
    return $this->newQuery()->paginate(10, $columns, $this->getTable(), $page)->appends($params);
}
```

Now, all you need to do is `Model::superPaginate(10);` and `$models->render()`. Everything should work properly.